# Prism interactivity confirmation—callback or no callback?

Tags: wpf, prism, interactive

When using `InteractionRequest` with `Confirmation` and *synchronous* `Raise`, there are two ways of getting the result of the confirmation. The most popular way seems to be:

```
Confirmation confirmation = new Confirmation()
{
    Title = "Confirmation",
    Content = "Do you really want to do this?"
};
DeleteConfirmationRequest.Raise(confirmation, c => {
    if (c.Confirmed)
    {
        // do something terrible
    }
});
```

However, since I don't really care in this case whether the user cancelled the request or didn't even subscribe to the confirmation, I can do this instead:

```
Confirmation confirmation = new Confirmation()
{
    Title = "Confirmation",
    Content = "Do you really want to do this?"
};
DeleteConfirmationRequest.Raise(confirmation);
if (confirmation.Confirmed)
{
    // do something terrible
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no real difference between these two. Am I right, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `synchronous` = a `PopupWindowAction` with `IsModal=true` for example? In this case, the variant without the callback is fine, I guess. Although the callback-variant is safer, if implementations change, and, for example, the action's `Invoke` doesn't block anymore or the `Confirmation` is cloned internally and the callback doesn't get the same instance you passed in...

Comment: @Haukinger, this should really be an answer, not a comment. Short, but to the point. I haven't thought about cloning and modality variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean *synchronous* = a PopupWindowAction with `IsModal=true` for example? 
In this case, the variant without the callback is fine, I guess.

Although the callback-variant is safer if implementations change, and, for example, the action's `Invoke` doesn't block anymore or the `Confirmation` is cloned internally and the callback doesn't get the same instance you passed in...